# How do I draw a polygon in python?

Tags: python, geometry, pygame

I have watched Professor Craven's video about drawing a polygon in Python:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qvsevlb5pg&list=PL1D91F4E6E79E73E1&index=22

His videos are very useful for beginners.
His explanations are very helpful, so are the examples.
When I tried his example:

```
pygame.draw.polygon(screen, black, [[100,100],[0,200],[200,200]], 5)
```

It worked just fine.
However, when I tried something of my own, it drew only a line:

```
pygame.draw.polygon(screen, black, [[300,200],[150,100],[450,300]],6)
```

What is my mistake?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The points (150, 100), (300,200), and (450,300) are collinear. The polygon they form is effectively an extremely flat triangle.

[image]

Try varying one of the points so that it doesn't line up with the other two.

```
pygame.draw.polygon(screen, black, [[300,400],[150,100],[450,300]],6)
```

---

In the future, it may be useful to check for collinearity before drawing, so you know you'll get a real shape. Generally, you can determine whether a collection of points are collinear, by comparing the slopes of the line segments they form together.

Line AB's slope is (200-100)/(300-150) = 2/3.

Line BC's slope is (300-100)/(450-150) = 2/3.

Line AC's slope is (300-200)/(450-300) = 2/3.

The slopes are all equal, so the points must all lie on the same line.